# Unable to install tokenizers in Mac M1

Tags: python-3.x, apple-m1, huggingface-tokenizers

I installed the transformers in the Macbook Pro M1 Max

Following this, I installed the tokenizers with

```
pip install tokenizers
```

It showed

> Collecting tokenizers
> Using cached tokenizers-0.12.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl
> Successfully installed tokenizers-0.12.1

It seems to use the correct architecture for the whl file

When I import it I get

> '/Users/myname/miniforge3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))

I see that this problem used to happen to others before. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

**James Briggs** method works but produces the following error

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**The Issue**

After installing Rust and Cargo, we must source the environment file. This is the missing step in the previous answer.

**The Solution**

The workaround to solving this is to type the following in the terminal, right after installing Rust:

```
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

Then, you can install transformers with the following code snippet:

```
pip install transformers
```

Comment: Is James Briggs' method at the bottom of Emerson Pedroso's answer? Ie, install rust with `curl — proto ‘=https’ — tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`? Didn't work for me (using pip not conda).

Comment: @Chris, yes it is Emerson Pedroso's answer. I answered this a long time back, so I don't particularly remember all the details.

I tested it with `pip install transformers` in a new venv, seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 3):

If using Anaconda we switch to a terminal window and create a new ARM environment like so:

```
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64 conda create -n ml python=3.9 -c conda-forge
```

now get in to ml envoriment

```
conda activate ml
```

run inside the env

```
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-arm64
```

needs to restart env

```
conda deactivate
```

get into to env

```
conda activate ml
```

**PyTorch Installation**
To get started we need to install PyTorch v1.12. For now, this is only available as a nightly release.

```
pip3 install -U --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

Side note: The transformers library uses tokenizers built in Rust (it makes them faster). Because we are using this new ARM64 environment we may get ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers. If so, we install Rust (in the same environment) with:

```
curl — proto ‘=https’ — tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

restart your env

```
conda deactivate 
conda activate ml
```

than you can install transformer comes with tokenizers or only install tokenizers

```
pip install tokenizers or pip install transformer
```

**thanks to James Briggs**

Comment: I tried this, same problem

Comment: try using conda install tokenizers

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
conda install -c huggingface transformers
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing most of the solutions provided I finally got it working by doing

```
brew install ffmpeg
sudo pip install tokenizers
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too. Solved it after a lot of trial & error.

The Problem: my brew was still running on Rosetta. Fixed that by uninstalling, cleaning and reinstalling. So everything seemed to run fine. Except this problem still kept cropping up

Until I discovered that pip is quite agressive in caching. So it caches the build even if the architecture changed. Solution: pip cache purge. Or remove the whole cache directory which you find with pip cache info